# Cloud Functions in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

i've a database structure like this:

```
root: {
       timer: 1,
       data: {
                id1: val,
                id2: val,
       },
       cronology: {
                id:{
                       id1: val,
                       id2: val,
                },
                id:{
                       id1: val,
                       id2: val,
                }
         }
```

I'm trying to make a trigger that, when the timer value is modified, it adds to cronology a child that contains the actual values of the path: '/data'.
So i created a function with the onUpdate method on the DatabaseReference '/timer'. The problem is that i  don't know how to access to '/data' values in this function

```
export const cronologyBuilder = functions.database.ref("/timer")
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newdata = admin.database.ref('/data');

    return admin.database.ref('/cronology').set(newdata);
});
```

I tried with this code but it tells me that newdata object is not good for set method.
How can i get the values of '/data' path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not actually querying for any data.  This line of code just builds a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) object.  It does not contain any data:

```
const newdata = admin.database.ref('/data');
```

If you want to query that location, you will need to call [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) on it and use the returned promise to wait for the data at that location:

```
return admin.database.ref('/data').once('value')
.then(snapshot => {
    return admin.database.ref('/cronology').set(snapshot.val());
})
```

I suggest reading the documentation for the [Admin SDK database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to learn how to read and write data.  You will also need to understand how promises work in order to deal with them properly.